# Change Colors Depending on the Hour of the Day

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a html doc that has three images on the bottom of the page. All of these images have borders on them. At a certain point in the day the images will have different color border on them, so the first one will start on green the other two will be red, and then the middle will be green and the outer two will be red.

I am having a lot of trouble getting any code to change those border color's, let alone getting them to work in conjunction with conditional statements.

This is what my `index.html` sections looks like that src's the images

```
<div id="shippingLogos">
    <img src="images/FedExground.jpg" alt="FedEx Ground" class="shipGround"/>
    <img src="images/UPS.jpg" alt="UPS" class="shipUPS" />
    <img src="images/FedEx_Express.png" alt="FedEx Express" class="shipExpress" />
</div>
```

The class then goes to my `style.css` file where the corresponding class names are used

```
img.shipGround
{
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 10px;
    float: left;
    height:300px;
    margin: 30px 38px 30px 38px;
    width:25%;
}
```

I already have the borders in place and all I am trying to do is use jscript/jquery to change that border color. I left out the border-color completely because I wanted to know where you guys think I should put it.

I have tried several different approaches and I cannot get it to work, any advise is much appreciated.

Comment: border-color: #XXXXXX;    - `$(".shipGround").css("border-color", "#XXXXXX");`  
of course where `XXXXXX` is your hex color code

Comment: What is supposed to trigger the border color change?

Comment: @DrydenLong the time/hour of the day

Comment: @DrydenLong phase of the moon?

Comment: Nevermind, I must have skipped over that part... @RokoC.Buljan Good eye, thanks!

Comment: And how does the time of day relate to which `img`'s border should be green, and which red?

Answer (score 1):

**Simple as that: http://jsbin.com/uqeyeg/3/edit**

```
var idx = Math.floor( (new Date().getHours()/24) * 3 );
$("#shippingLogos img").eq( idx ).addClass('green');
```

`idx` will return `0, 1, 2` depending on the hour of the day <sup>(24h/8h=3parts)</sup>. 
Using that value now you can easily target the children `img` using the jQuery `.eq()` method.

**HTML**: (you don't need any class at all :) huray! )

```
<div id="shippingLogos">
    <img src="images/FedExground.jpg" alt="FedEx Ground" />
    <img src="images/UPS.jpg" alt="UPS" />
    <img src="images/FedEx_Express.png" alt="FedEx Express" />
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
#shippingLogos img {
  border: 10px solid red; /* MAKE RED DEFAULT */
  float: left;
  height:300px;
  margin: 30px 3%;
  width:24%;
}

.green{
  border: 10px solid green !important; /* APPLIED BY jQuery */
}
```

**EDIT:** <sup>as suggested by DavidThomas - worth mentioning</sup>

If you'll ever need to make the code more flexible eg: you'll have 6 images and you want to split your *day* into 6 than you can do:

```
var $images = $("#shippingLogos img"),
    NofImages = $images.length,
    idx = Math.floor( (new Date().getHours()/24) * NofImages );

$images.eq( idx ).addClass('green');
```

**Conclusion:** 
as you've seen we just replaced the *old* `3` and used the `NofImages` that are representing the number of the day-parts.

Comment: To make it more extensible, you could show how to use this with a dynamic number of images...(but up-voted anyway)

Comment: Yeah, just thought it was worth suggesting, maybe; if only because of the relative inexperience of the OP. Hardly a necessity, though.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a class for the highlighted color:

```
.highlight {
    border-color: red;
}
```

then, set that class using Javascript (suppose you use jQuery):

```
var date = new Date();
var hours = date.getHours();
$("#shippingLogos").children().removeClass('highlight');
if(hours >= 0 && hours < 8){
    $("#shippingLogos").children().eq(0).addClass('highlight');
}else if(hours >=8 && hours < 16){
    $("#shippingLogos").children().eq(1).addClass('highlight');
} else {
    $("#shippingLogos").children().eq(2).addClass('highlight');
}
```

Comment: And, if user2476299 wants border color animation, maybe this could help: http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/color-animation/

Answer (score 0):

While the specific problems in your question have been answered by the top-voted comments, the answers could be expanded upon to change or *animate* css properties of your choosing in real-time according to the hour number of day or even according to the actual daylight at your particular location on the earth.

Here is a demo and source I've written with a small amount of php to change css properties based on the daylight at a given location

**for a demo see here:**
http://shawnfromportland.com/circadianCssWithPhp/

**for the source check it out here:**
https://github.com/shawnfromportland/circadianCssWithPhp